# Tick a radio button with a nodejs post request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do a post request with radio buttons.
HTML page is a form has 2 radio buttons :

```
<form name="create" class="jqTransform FormValidate" id="MyForm" action="/My/Form/1" method="post">
<p class="a"><input type="radio" class="radio" value="1" name="choices" id="18" /><label for="r1">Radio button r1</label></p>
<p class="a"><input type="radio" class="radio" value="2" name="choices" id="r2" /><label for="r2">Radio button R2</label></p>
<input type="submit" class="Bbutton" title="Click here to go to next step" value="next step" name="nextStep" />
```

And I would like to chose either R1 or R2 in a post request like this one:

```
request({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        form: {
             //Here maybe ? something to add for checking a radio button?
            nextStep: 'next step',
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'MyUserAgent',
            'Referer': 'https://myurl/My/Form/1'
        },
        jar: jar
    }, function(err, response, body) {do something after}
```

I know it is possible to tick a checkbox with

```
condition: 'on'
```

Inside the request form parameters.
But I don't know how to proceed to check a radio button.

Any help appreciated !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a noob in nodejs.

Answer :

```
choices : 1
```

inside the form.